# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition Installation in Windows 10 - SSRS connection issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssms, failed-installation

I have a new laptop with Windows 10 (64-bit) Professional. The IT team has installed the Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Express Edition. I am not at all familiar with this 2017 edition.(I see Management Studio 17).

Now:

I have installed SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition in this machine with Windows authentication only. I am able to see all the service engines running successfully - Database Engine, Reporting Services Engine, Integration Services Engine - in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

I am able to connect to the DB Engine, SSAS Engine, and SSIS Engine from SSMS 2012. However, I am **not** able to connect to SSRS 2012 Engine from SSMS 2012. I am also **not** able to get into the SSRS Report Server URL or SSRS Report Manager URL (I see that  - 'This page can’t be displayed').

This said, I **do** see the ReportServer database and ReportServerTempDB database successfully installed in the DB Engine.

**What should I do to connect SSRS 2012 from SSMS ? How to make the SSRS Report Server and SSRS Report Manager work successfully?**

Error I get when I connect to SSRS 2012 from SSMS 2012:

TITLE: Connect to Server

---

Cannot connect to LAPTOPNAME\SQL2012DEV.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Unable to connect to the server at LAPTOPNAME\SQL2012DEV. The specified URL might not be valid or there might be a problem with the report server version or configuration. Specify a different URL, or contact your server administrator to verify that the report server runs SQL Server 2008 or later. Additionally, if you are trying to connect to a SharePoint-integrated report server, verify that SharePoint is installed on the server and that the report server uses SharePoint integrated mode. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient)

---

BUTTONS:

OK

---

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out.

The IT team changed the IP of my machine and added me into the Multi Media group.

Now I am able to view the Report Manager and Report Server URL as well as connect to the SSRS Engine via SSMS.

Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate the error on my machine running SQL server 2012, if I stop the SSRS service.  To restart the SSRS service, go to 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012' then 'Configuration Tools' open 'SQL Server Configuration Manager'.  Click on [image: SQL Server Services node], then look at SQL Server Reporting Services, if it is stopped, then start the service.   Once the service is running you should be able to connect to the SSRS instance.

Comment: Even after restarting, I face the same issues. I see the SSRS engine running fine before and after the restart. But not able to connect to SSRS via SSMS or Report Manager/Report Server web URL

Comment: Can you confirm when you installed SQL 2012 you installed all the required components eg SSRS?  It was a named instance called 'SQL2012DEV' you installed.  Also, you granted the windows account you logged in with Admin privileges?  It is the same windows account you are currently login in with and try to connect with?

Answer (score 0):

I am again facing the same issue. I believe the problem is due to permission issues.  How do I provide Admin privileges to the Windows user account that I am using ?